# preventing Selenium test database from being deleted in Django between tests

Tags: django, selenium

Using Selenium within Django I'm trying to run 2 acceptance tests on my django app. The first test registers a new user of my app, the second one logs that user in to the system and tries to perform an action. However, when running the tests, between the first and second tests, the user is erased from the database. It seems the database is wiped between each test. All the documentation I have seen indicates this isn't supposed to be happening.
How can I prevent this from occurring?

Note: Both the setUpClass and tearDownClass methods of my Test Class have @classmethod decorators. Also, the browser doesn't close between the two tests running.

Comment: Could this not be your test working, and finding a flaw in your database code? Have you tried putting both of the tests' logic into a single test and seeing if it finds the user then?

Comment: When combining them all into one method, it works fine.

Comment: The code can be seen at http://dpaste.com/748576/.

Comment: It is possible you are not writing to your database correctly (non testing code issue) and it is not storing it outside of the browser session. I do know that logins do not remain logged in (my experience anyway) after 'killing' a browser.